# Struts 1.2 server-Side JavaScript Validation

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, struts-1

I am new  to struts , I need a serverside Java script Validation in struts 1.2. I did a lot of googling but did not get anything useful

Server side validation with page refersh and page error is easy , But i do not have idea about how to prompt with Javascript and then display the same jsp page

Thanks in advance

any link , simple example could be useful

Comment: Server-side JavaScript validation *might* make sense, but I bet that's not really what you mean.

Comment: Pointy I  need to Validate one text input from DB and if user will click OK then I need to insert it , else rollback.

Comment: Right. Your server-side code is all Java. Why exactly do you need for this validation code to be JavaScript?

Comment: Like  user enter his phone number and Name ,and  if any other phn number is registered with his name (Database Validation) Then I need a pop up a JavaScript that any other number is already registered with this number , Do you want to update it , If user click Ok then insert and then display same page and if click no then do nothin..Do tell me if this makes sense

Comment: Not a lot. Do you mean you want to validate via Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you https://github.com/koorchik/LIVR 
I  use this long time
For try you can use http://webbylab.github.io/livr-playground

Comment: Link-only answers aren't really appropriate for SO. Include the main points in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the client side form validation, you can try bootstrap validator as following

> ```
> $('#yourForm')
>     .formValidation({
>         framework: 'bootstrap',
>         icon: {
>             valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
>             invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
>             validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
>         },
>         fields: {
>             email: {
>                 validators: {
>                  notEmpty: {
>                   message: 'Please provide email address'
>                  },
>                  emailAddress: {
>                         message: 'The value is not a valid email address'
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     })
> ```

If you want to validate the email is already registered in the database, you need javascript Ajax call.

Comment: Can you kindly provide an example or url for ajax call server side validation in Struts 1.2 (Please answer as per Strtus 1.x)

Comment: I use DWR(Direct Web Remoting) for that. It expose/map the java objects on the server with the javascript objects with method. So that the client page can call the java methods using exposed javascript objects. See more on http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/index.html